# Json-schema.Как включить в регулярное выражение для валидации string возможное наличие пробельных символов?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, json

Всем привет!
Для валидации `json` использую библиотеку

https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema.

Сделал следующую схему:

```
{
  "id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "comment": "Schema for category validation during creation",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 128,
      "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$"
    }
  },
  "required": ["name"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Она работает, но не так как нужно, а именно: она не допускает пробельные символы в валидируемой строке. такое регулярное выражение с включением `\t` или `\s` (пример: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+$"`) не проходит: phpunit выдает `JSON syntax is malformed`. Если кто в курсе дела - прошу подсказать.

Answer (score 2):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+$` здесь у вас вместо того, чтобы перечислить знак `-` и пробельный символ `\s`, получается некорректный диапазон `_-\s` (между подчеркиванием и пробельным символом). Можно поставить `\s` в начало например: `^[\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+$`.

Второй момент - знак `\` в `pattern` надо экранировать. Итоговый вариант:

```
"pattern": "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+$"
```

Ещё одна мелочь: `id` по идее должен быть уникальным для вашей схемы, например `"id": "http://yourdomain.com/schemas/myschema.json"`, у вас же он совпадает с полем `"$schema"`. Но на деле валидаторам это не важно.

P.S.
Регулярные выражения можно быстро проверить онлайн на https://regex101.com/. Свою схему на валидность можно проверить на http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ выбрав слева `Schema draft v4`, а справа вставив свою схему.